# How does changing a domain name in Office 365 affect user authentication for Azure Active Directory attached computers?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

We are changing our domain name.  In the Office 365 the change is seamless regarding authentication for email, SharePoint, One Drive.  People will sign into Office 365 with thier new username/email address and those services will work fine. The question has to do with Azure Directory attached computers.  Currently users sign into thier comptuers with their email address for the old domain.  Will the comptuers automatically switch to the new domain when I add it to the Office 365 tenent and switch the email address for everyone. This is **not** a hybrid system. It is **not** syncing with an on-premises domain. It is **not** part of any federatated system. Just straight up Azure Active Directory attached computers.  I  would like to get anwser for this qustion before I switch people over.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not changing the tenant to which the computers are attached (registered or joined) you should see no change. Users will sign in using the new domain name, however still targeting the same directory (tenant).